# случайные картинки на сайте

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью чего и как сделать такое.
Задание чтоб на сайте при нажатии на кнопку показало одну из 3 случайных картинок, которые ранее не отображались на сайте.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: а как картинку получаются? где хранится?

Comment: не плохоыб сразу иметь сслыки на все картинки

Comment: "ранее не отображались на сайте" это значит что они не показывались и на других страницах сайта которые посетил пользователь? Тогда надо хранить информацию по тем картинкам которые уже отображались в куках (если уж метка к вопросу javascript), а лучше на стороне сервера в сессии пользователя.

Answer (score 4):

```
const images = [
        'f1.jpg',
        'f2.jpg',
        'f3.jpg'
    ]

    var index = 0; // это сколько раз нажали на кнопку
    var ing = document.getElementById('img') // это наш тег картинка
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn') // это наша кнопка

    btn.onclick = () => {
        if (!images.length) {
            alert('нет картинок');
            return;
        }

        ing.setAttribute('src', images[index]);
            images.splice(index,1);
index++;

    }
```

Comment: а как картинку получаются? где хранится?
Первого вопроса не понял
Хранятся у меня на компьютере.
Я только недавно начал изучать javascript, это я делаю всё для себя, чтоб практиковать.Столкнувшись с данной задачей я не смог найти инфы в интернете.Может вы подскажите как такое "гуглить"?

Comment: в моем пример не рандома они тупо все по порядку показываются хотя какой рандом из 3 картинок  хотя с 10 взять

Comment: можно и из 10 сделать,мне не принципиально, хотелось бы понять как это делается